# ExtJS (5) Sencha build configurations for different environments

Tags: extjs, build, environment-variables

I have an ExtJS 5.0 app that points to an API. On **development**, I'd like to use `http://localhost` but on **production** of course some other server.

Is there a way to set an app's variable from the outside during `sencha app build` ? Or access some ENV variable in the code?

Would be great if anybody could help me.

Thank you very much,

Sebastian

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a way of doing this but I am not sure it is the best way. In your app.json you will find a section like this:

```
/**
 * override objects for setting build environment specific 
 * settings.
 */
"production": {
    banana : 'no'
},
"testing": {
    banana : 'yes'
},
"development": {

},
```

Obviously I have added the banana field myself. We are not allowed to deploy a banana in production so I set the value yes or no based on the environment.

Then at build whether I do 'sencha app build testing' or 'sencha app build production' it will build in the respective banana value for the environment into the Ext.manifest object.

So in the application I can access the value through:

```
if (Ext.manifest.banana === "yes")
```

I presume you can use the same technique to define fields for other fruit, or perhaps even non-fruit related data.

I got the idea from this document:
"When you launch your application, you will find the processed content of app.json loaded as “Ext.manifest”."
http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/microloader.html

Like I said I don't know if this is the best way to do it but I suspect it might be.

Comment: Cool, it worked! Thanks a lot for your quick and detailed answer

Comment: "For locally overriding build properties, the build script loads an optional properties file called "local.properties" if present in your app folder. The purpose of this file is to define build properties that are in some way special to the local environment (that is, the local machine). As such, this file is not intended to be tracked in source control."

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.3.0/guides/cli_reference.html